# Displaying image uploaded in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have uploaded the image and stored in the path Application/Photo but somehow I am unable to retrieve it.

```
<?php
$app = $_POST['app'];
$dbLink = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','another');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lama WHERE app = '$app'";
$sth = mysqli_query($dbLink,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {?>
<img src="Application/Photo/ <?php echo $row['photoname']; ?>" height="250px" width="190px"/>
<?php
}
?>
//Below is the code I used to upload the image

$puploads_dir = 'Application/Photo';

$pname = $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
$tname=$_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];

$photoname = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extensionp = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 $incrementp = 0; 
 $pname = $photoname . '.' . $extensionp;
 while(is_file($puploads_dir.'/'.$pname)) {
 $incrementp++;
 $pname = $photoname . $incrementp . '.' . $extensionp;
 }
 move_uploaded_file($tname, $puploads_dir.'/'.$pname);
 $query = "
        INSERT INTO `lama` (
            `photoname` )
        VALUES (
         '{$pname}')";
```

I have also uploaded the code I used for uploading the image.

Comment: Can you show us the data contained in column 'photoname'?

Comment: $_FILES["photo"]["name"];

Comment: it look like you have a space in your image src before printing photoname

Comment: So, the code is in the database? That will not work, you'll need the actual name of the image. The `$_FILE` array will be empty at the time you try to display the image. There is a problem with your saving the data to the database if you have code stored there.

Comment: I have also uploaded the code I used for uploading the image. Please take a look

Comment: The image is in the Path Application/Photo/ too

Comment: Can you please check and show what image src gets print in browser via "inspect element" or "view source"

Comment: Funny..... Sorry Guys its because of the Space in the SRC as pointed out by @Arbaz Khan